# Checking if point is to north/south of shape

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I have a shape file of a mountain range and a bunch (about 4000) of coordinates that lie, both north and south of the said mountain range. I want to simply determine whether a given point is to the north or south of the mountain range (and distance from the mountain range if possible), then return the output for each point as a csv or an equivalent form.

I have been using Google's Earth Engine on Python and so far I have just been able to map the shapefile and the coordinates for the points on a basemap.

Is there a method to carry out this check on geemap?

This is my code so far

```
Map = geemap.Map(center=[center_lat,center_lon], zoom=zoomlevel)
Map
mountain_shp = 'Path of shp file'
mountain = geemap.shp_to_ee(Mountain_shp)
Map.addLayer(mountain, {}, 'Mountain')
in_csv = 'path of csv with lat-lon of points'
df = geemap.csv_to_pandas(in_csv)
Map.add_xy_data(in_csv, x="longnum", y="latnum", layer_name="csv to ee", to_ee=True)
```

Which gives me:

[image]

but I need to identify, for each point, the distance and direction from the black-solid line (which is the shape of my mountain range.

Comment: Why are you using GEE? Any GIS software can easily answer this question for example the [near](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) tool in ArcMap\ArcPro.

Comment: Sorry, don't have access to ArcGIS

Comment: QGIS? Thats free...